# object_detail() got multiple values for keyword argument 'queryset' while inputting only one

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-generic-views

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.conf import settings
from Website.Blog.models import Post
# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

index = {
            'queryset': Post.objects.all(),
            'date_field': 'created_on',
            'template_name': 'index.html',
            'num_latest': 5
        }

post =  {
            'template_name': 'index.html',
            'queryset': Post.objects.all(), # only here, what could be wrong?
            'slug': 'slug',
        }

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Example:
    url(r'^$', 'django.views.generic.date_based.archive_index', index, name='index'),
    url(r'^post/(\S+)/$', 'django.views.generic.list_detail.object_detail', post, name='post'),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below and add 'django.contrib.admindocs' 
    # to INSTALLED_APPS to enable admin documentation:
    # (r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))
)


if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^css/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
        (r'^images/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.IMAGES_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True})
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `object_detail` view has `queryset` as the first positional argument. So the value that matches `(\S+)` in your regex for that url is being interpreted as the queryset arg, which is conflicting with the kwarg you are passing in the POST dictionary.

If you're trying to send the object_id as the matching element in the URL, you'll need to use a named group:

```
url(r'^post/(?P<object_id>\S+)/$' ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `?:` to the groups (parentheses) that you don't want to be passed on to the view function.
Like this:

`url(r'^post/(?:\S+)/$', 'django.views.generic.list_detail.object_detail', post, name='post'),`

See this article for more info:
http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/oct/14/url-patterns/