# Getting django error in the view with custom function

Tags: python, django

I am using django class based view

```
class MyView(TemplateView):
    def return_JSON(self, object_id):
        parent = models.UserForm.objects.get(pk=object_id)

url(r'^return/(?P<object_id>\d+)/json/', views.MyView().return_JSON, name="return_json")
```

I get this error

```
return_JSON() got multiple values for keyword argument 'object_id'
```

Comment: go through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13544504/django-form-got-multiple-values-for-keyword-argument & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387766/object-detail-got-multiple-values-for-keyword-argument-queryset-while-inputt

Comment: i tried putting request in the function then i get `object has no attribute 'request'`

Answer (score 3):

You're doing something very odd here.

You're using CBVs, but passing a function as the view function. Remember, the normal signature for CBVs is to pass in `MyCBV.as_view()`. No CBV machinery runs without running it through `as_view()` or `dispatch()`.

But if you insist, you just need to add a new argument to your function...

```
def return_JSON(self, request, object_id):
    #                 ^^^^^^^ this
    return http.HttpResponse("Foo!")
```

Comment: i tried that and i get this error `object has no attribute 'request'`

Comment: That makes no sense. There is nothing referencing a `request` attribute anywhere in this code. Post your traceback. Also, for future reference, you're missing KEY information. ***which*** object has no attribute `request`? If you want to spit out a half line of debug information, include the important parts.